# Understanding this Switch statement

Tags: c++

So I tried running this piece of code and could not understand why it is giving me the output is giving me. If I input 4, why is the result 17?? I really don't get it. Can someone please explain?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int num;
    int alpha = 10;
    cout << "Enter a number :" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    switch(num) {
        case 3: 
            alpha++;
            break;
        case 4: 
        case 6: 
            alpha = alpha + 3;
        case 8: 
            alpha = alpha + 4;
            break;
        default: 
            alpha = alpha + 5;
    }

    cout << alpha << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Say, haven't you yet learned to use the preview and correct your formatting?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have any `break;`in the body of a`case`(or something else that would exit the case, like a`goto`) execution will continue with the next case statement (it will *fall through* as it's usually known).

In your case entering 4 will do first the `case 4:`, then fall through to`case 6:`and then to`case 8:`and the end result will be alpha (10) + 3 + 4 = 17. since the `case 8:`has a`break;`the switch statement will exit here.

On a side note, there's something called compound assignment `+=`that you can use to save some space, so instead of

```
alpha = alpha + 3;
```

you can do this:

```
alpha += 3;
```

Comment: So that's how it is..thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

A case statement works in the following way: The execution jumps to the matching case statement and continues until a break or the end of the switch block. Therefore, the statement after the case 8 is executed, too. So, 10+3+4=17.

Not writing a break at the end of a case block is considered as an error in most cases. In some cases it might be useful to continue with the execution, but this has to be commented very clearly to prevent confusions.